# Insert relative link in reStructuredText

Tags: documentation, restructuredtext, jsdoc

I am documenting a library that has a Python component and a JavaScript component. The overall user documentation, and the Python API documentation are in reStructuredText, processed with Sphinx. The JavaScript API is in jsdoc and is processed with jsdoc-toolkit.  The principal output format will be HTML.  I am new to reST, Sphinx and jsdoc.

I have set up a build system so all the generated html pages are dumped into a single directory tree.  I now need to insert into the main page (generated from reST) a link to the generated Javascript documentation.  This needs to be a relative link, since the docs may be located in different places on different installations.  reST will automatically parse a full URL, but I can't figure out how to make it insert a relative link. Constructs like [:ref:](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/markup/inline.html#role-ref) and [:doc:](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/markup/inline.html#role-doc) don't seem to help, because they expect the target to be reST.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Figured it out. The following inserts a relative reference to the document `js/index.html`:

```
`Javascript API <js/index.html>`_
```

Comment: Unless you are still looking for a better answer, you should accept your own answer. This way people that find your question in a search can see that it has a correct answer.

Comment: This reference will be useful: http://hyperpolyglot.org/lightweight-markup

Comment: do you know what to do if you need to go up the tree, i.e. something like `<../js/index.html>` - which seems to be ignored by sphinx